# Concatenate string to list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, concatenation

I am trying to join a string to a list of dictionaries. I am doing:

```
print(site + ', '.join(search_res))
```

I keep getting an error: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found`

```
search_res = [
    {
        "book": "Harry Potter",
        "rating": "10.0"
    },
    {
        "book": "Lord of The Rings",
        "rating": "9.0"
    }
]

site = "Fantasy"
```

Expected result:

```
"Fantasy" , [
    {
        "book": "Harry Potter",
        "rating": "10.0"
    },
    {
        "book": "Lord of The Rings",
        "rating": "9.0"
    }
]
```

How do I concatenate the string to the list of dictionaries without getting the `sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found` error

Comment: What is your expected result? A string, a dict, or a tuple?

Comment: This `[site] +  search_res`?

Comment: the items of the argument passed to `join` cannot be dictionaries; they have to be strings.. This is what the error tells you. What are you trying to do and (most likely) why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `print(site + str(search_res))`?

Also you could do: `print(site + ', '.join([str(dic) for dic in search_res)])`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need this:
`print(site + ' , ' + str(search_res))`

Answer (score 0):

> How do I concatenate the string to the list of dictionaries

You can't. And you don't need to either. Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting),  possibly together with [the `pprint` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint).